# Indexing mind maps for full text search in Alfresco?

Tags: search, indexing, alfresco, mindmapping, freemind

I'm looking for a way to index the contents of .mm files on Alfresco 4.1 for Windows 7 so I can search within each mind map.  So far I've found a [promising method](http://thinkalfresco.blogspot.com/2009/02/indexing-freemind-mindmaps-with.html) however I can't seem to get it to work.

The best way seems to be extracting each .mm file's text by getting the values of each node's text attribute.  An XSLT in the method posted renders all the text clearly in a web browser after renaming the mind map to an xml, then adding the xml prologue and stylesheet tags.  Can't seem to figure out a more elegant solution so Alfresco searches each mind map as if it were an XML, yet still returns an .mm file.  The method I've already found suggests using xmlstarlet from within Alfresco's RuntimeExecutableContentTransformer bean.  However this resulted in a server missing resource error when I tried it on Windows.

Does anyone have a step by step process for implementing full text searching of mind maps?

Greatly appreciate any kind of help you may have.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco will automatically extract the text content of XML files using Tika and will populate the index using this.

Try setting the MIME type of your `.mm` files to XML in Alfresco and they should be indexed automatically.

If that works and you want `.mm` files to be automatically indexed when they are added to the repository, you could add the file extension to the list of extensions for the `text/xml` MIME type in the config file `alfresco/mimetype/mimetype-map.xml`.